# How to add an array of images to a Mongo database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I use a formidable plugin and I only work on one image, when I upload several images together the code overwrites the next image and does not display,
I want to add an array of images to the database

my code :

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
    form.multiples = true;
    form.keepExtensions = true;

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) =>{
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "Image could not be uploaded"
            });
        }

        //check for all fields
        const { name, description, price, category, quantity, shipping, color, size } = fields;
        
        if (!name || !description || !price || !category || !quantity || !shipping || !color || !size) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "All fields are required"
                });
        }

        let product = new Product(fields);
        const file = files;
        if(files.photo){
            for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++){
            if(files.photo.size > 1000000) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "Image should be less then 1mb in size"
                });
            }
            product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
            product.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
        }}
        product.save((err, result) =>{
            if(err){
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: errorHandler(error)
                });
            }
            res.json(result);
            console.log(result)
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Well you need an array of objects not a single object. That is most likely why its not saving. Also, javascript is non blocking so its running product.save before your for loop ever finishes. If you need more assistance I can provide example code as an answer

Comment: If you can it would be great

Comment: okay reading over your code and its a little confusing. I am not sure what product is or how it is use. However, the code below should help you.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above, I am confused on what Product is. I don't understand the need or why you have a for loop. The file/ files terminology is also confusing. Do you have one file or multiple files. The naming convention used below should help ease that.

Anyways, I hope the code below helps you. Also, you don't need to return an express function. You only need to call `res.status`

```
const Create = (req, res) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm({ multiples: true, keepExtensions: true });

  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'Image could not be uploaded',
      });
    }

    //check for all fields
    const { name, description, price, category, quantity, shipping, color, size } = fields;

    if (!name || !description || !price || !category || !quantity || !shipping || !color || !size) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'All fields are required',
      });
    }

    const tooLarge = files.filter((file) => file.photo.size > 1000000);

    if (tooLarge[0]) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: 'Image should be less then 1mb in size',
      });
    } else {
      const products = files.map((file) => {
        const product = new Product(fields);
        product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(file.photo.path);
        product.photo.contentType = file.photo.type;
      });
    }
    products.save((err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: err,
        });
      }
      res.json(results);
    });
  });
};

export default Create;
```

Comment: Okay so did you debug? what isn't working?

Comment: TypeError: files.filter is not a function

Comment: Okay so what is files. is files an array of objects? you are looping over files in your example. Maybe you should rewrite your sentence to include more details.

Comment: files I get the array of objects of the images.
I want to run on them and show all the pictures in the product I uploaded from the site.
In the example I run on one image at a time but I want to upload some together

Comment: if its a valid array object then filter will work. again I don't know what your array looks like. You didn't provide that information .

Answer (score 0):

I selected 4 images and uploaded with all the details of the product this is the information from files

```
  {
  photo0: File {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    size: 35640,
    path: 'C:\\Users\\Don\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_f486007f37df6694692eee8c3115ee02.jpg',
    name: '1.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    hash: null,
    lastModifiedDate: 2021-04-11T10:32:20.708Z,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      path: 'C:\\Users\\Don\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_f486007f37df6694692eee8c3115ee02.jpg',
      fd: null,
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      autoClose: true,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 35640,
      closed: true,
      [Symbol(kFs)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  photo1: File {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    size: 34441,
    path: 'C:\\Users\\Don\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_8e5297114be470785dae2a66b7bb37f4.jpg',
    name: '2.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    hash: null,
    lastModifiedDate: 2021-04-11T10:32:20.710Z,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      path: 'C:\\Users\\Don\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_8e5297114be470785dae2a66b7bb37f4.jpg',
      fd: null,
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      autoClose: true,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 34441,
      closed: true,
      [Symbol(kFs)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  photo2: File {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    size: 45006,
    path: 'C:\\Users\\Don\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_b91717c799d0d3f55836fc423903854a.jpg',
    name: '6.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    hash: null,
    lastModifiedDate: 2021-04-11T10:32:20.711Z,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      path: 'C:\\Users\\Don\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_b91717c799d0d3f55836fc423903854a.jpg',
      fd: null,
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      autoClose: true,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 45006,
      closed: true,
      [Symbol(kFs)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  photo3: File {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    size: 45443,
    path: 'C:\\Users\\Don\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_3c152be1e96131bba2597372df9f1777.jpg',
    name: 'AEROREADY_Designed_2_Move_Sport_Stretch_Tee_Black_GM2074_21_model.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    hash: null,
    lastModifiedDate: 2021-04-11T10:32:20.711Z,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      path: 'C:\\Users\\Don\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_3c152be1e96131bba2597372df9f1777.jpg',
      fd: 7,
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      autoClose: true,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 45443,
      closed: false,
      [Symbol(kFs)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
}
```